# Can't access Interpreter settings in Zeppelin

Tags: shiro, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-zeppelin

I'm using Zeppelin in my Hortonworks Data Platform 2.5 cluster.

Since I set `zeppelin.anonymous.allowed=false` I'm not able to enter my interpreter settings anymore - The interpreter screen is empty, see this screenshot:
[image]

My `shiro_ini_content` contains the following `[users]`, `[roles]` and `[urls]` settings:

```
[users]
admin = passw0rd, administrator

[main]
shiro.loginUrl = /api/login

[roles]
administrator = *

[urls]
/api/version = anon
#/** = anon
/** = authc
/api/interpreter/** = authc, roles[administrator]
/api/configurations/** = authc, roles[administrator]
/api/credential/** = authc, roles[administrator]
```

I made the settings based on the following manual: https://shiro.apache.org/configuration.html#Configuration-%5Croles%5C

Why am I still unable to access the Interpreter settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It need also `sessionManager` settings in your `[main]` section like below.

```
[main]
shiro.loginUrl = /api/login

sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
# 86,400,000 milliseconds = 24 hour
securityManager.sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 86400000
```

Could you try?

Comment: Great, that part was missing - Thank you very much!